# adding a superscript or subscript to a button title using the interface builder in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, unicode, uibutton, interface-builder, xcode8

I would like to create a button who's title is x squared but I cannot find any info on how to add a superscript to the x.  All I can find is how to create subscripts and superscripts in pages or in word.  I don't want to have to copy and paste.  Is there a way to do it using the interface builder in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

### x²

The only way to implement the *superscript two* in Storyboard is to paste it directly. The unicode character code is `U+00B2`.

[image]

That’s what it looks like when it’s inside a Bar Button item.

[image]

Unfortunately, it’s still not possible to enable and apply OpenType features from macOS Typography panel to Storyboard elements.

Fortunately, `U+00B2` is true superior/superscript version, and not a fake one that can be invoked in TextEdit or Pages menu (Format > Font > Baseline > Superscript).

You can find numerous examples on Stack Overflow on how to create fake ones — by decreasing the font size and raising the baseline. This is completely wrong way to do it. Avoid it.

If you’d like to implement the feature via code, here is the way to do it for the system font:

```
let systemFontDescriptor = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0).fontDescriptor
let superscriptFontDescriptor = systemFontDescriptor.addingAttributes(
    [
        UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: [
            [
                UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kVerticalPositionType,
                UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kSuperiorsSelector,
            ],
        ]
    ]
)
button.font = UIFont(descriptor: superscriptFontDescriptor, size: 0.0)
```